# Create a new volume on free diskspace from inside Dom0

Tags: partition, lvm, mkfs

I have a server with two HDDs (/dev/sda and sdb) with 1.8TB each.

On both disks, there is a 500MB Swap and an 800GB partition, that are in a raid md0 and md1:

```
pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/md1   vg0  lvm2 a--  799,87g 63,87g
```

I am root in Dom0 and created a new partition /dev/sda3 in the former free space with `cfdisk`. Now it looks like:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    1050624    1048577  512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2          1052672 1678774272 1677721601  800G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       1678776320 3907029167 2228252848    1T 83 Linux
```

I want to use this free space as backupspace, so I don't want a raid here, but I cannot create a filesystem on /dev/sda3 now:

```
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The file /dev/sda3 does not exist and no size was specified.
```

And it doesn't appear in

```
# ls -l /dev/sda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Mai 24 22:07 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Mai 24 22:07 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Mai 24 22:07 /dev/sda2
```

How can I create a non-raid filesystem now in /dev/sda3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the kernel that the partition table has changed after you make any changes to partition tables with `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, or `parted` etc.

There are two main ways of doing this:

1. Reboot.  The kernel will detect the new partition table and use it automatically.
2. run `partprobe` as root.  This will tell the kernel to scan the block-device partitions and update its internal partition table records.

   `partprobe` is in the `parted` package. `apt-get install parted`

Until you do this, there will be no device node for the new parition(s) in `/dev`, so you will not be able to run `mkfs` to format it.